# ssh-agent is evoluting on it's own

Tags: ssh-agent

From my point of view the only config I had, was line

```
ssh-add -k
```

in my `.bashrc` and it was working. I.e. I was able to do `ssh -A` and was seeing my key with `ssh-add -l` on remote hosts.

Suddenly this line started to cause

```
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

and I read this means agent is not running and to run it I need to execute something like `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`

Why? How was it working before then?

Comment: The error could mean that while the agent may be alive and well, the communication socket was moved or deleted (see `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`).  A dead agent on an existing socket file would not give a "no such file or directory" error (I think).